# How to interact with mainnet smart contracts by GOlang?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, erc-20, etherscan, golang

Please tell me an example of code in GOlang that connects to the contract and checks the balance of the ERC20 token / transfer tokens / gets the name of the token. I looked for examples and did not find anything worthwhile, everything is connected to their local contract

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link
https://goethereumbook.org/smart-contract-read-erc20

for simplicity you can also directly use the package github.com/liyue201/erc20-go/erc20 and call the balance functions like this

```
func getERC20Balance(address string, tokenAddress string) big.Float {
    tokenAddressHex := common.HexToAddress(tokenAddress)
    addressHex := common.HexToAddress(tokenAddress)

    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    instance, err := erc20.NewGGToken(tokenAddressHex, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bal, err := instance.BalanceOf(nil, addressHex)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    name, err := instance.Name(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    symbol, err := instance.Symbol(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    decimals, err := instance.Decimals(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("name: %s\n", name)         // "name: Golem Network"
    fmt.Printf("symbol: %s\n", symbol)     // "symbol: GNT"
    fmt.Printf("decimals: %v\n", decimals) // "decimals: 18"

    fmt.Printf("wei: %s\n", bal) // "wei: 74605500647408739782407023"

    fbal := new(big.Float)
    fbal.SetString(bal.String())
    value := new(big.Float).Quo(fbal, big.NewFloat(math.Pow10(int(decimals))))

    fmt.Printf("balance: %f\n", value) // "balance: 74605500.647409"

    return *value

}
```

hope this helps!